# How to skip some steps, and continue the running of a model from a later point, bases on a condition?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, precondition, arcgis-10.8

I am building a Model in ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.
At some point in my model, I am dealing with Line feature classes. I turn them into Polygon feature classes, and then I merge them into one feature class.

The source of **my problem** is, that some of the inputs might be empty. If I run the *Feature To Polygon* tool with these inputs, it gives me the following error message:

`Error executing function. The geometry is not M-aware Failed to execute`

I tried to solve the problem, based on this thread: [Geometry is not M-Aware?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/geometry-is-not-m-aware). It didn't help. I am working in a geodatabase, and the M-aware option is turned off in the environmental settings.

I thought that preconditioning would work, so I tried (as you can see in the 3rd and 4th row of the attached image). The problem here is that it won't run the *Feature To Polygon* tool indeed, but it won't run anything after this tool either. So it won't eventually merge the other, not empty feature classes either.

Is there a way to skip some steps, based on a condition, and continue the running from an other point?

In my case, can I skip the *Feature To Polygon* and the *Calculate Field* tools if my feature class is empty, but then run the *Merge* tool with the other, not empty feature classes?

[image]

Comment: This should get you on the right path : https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/modelbuilder/using-if-then-else-logic-for-branching.htm

Comment: I did not mention in my question, but I also wrote a python script to tell if a FC is empty. The problem is the same. If the FC is **empty**, it won't run the tools on the **not empty** brcanch, and since it's one of the inputs for _Merge_, it won't run either. I just get a "All the inputs are not current" message for every FC that were empty.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any additional information.

Answer (score 4):

I have just spoofed up this model to simulate what you are doing and it all works fine for me! I'm using ArcMap 10.6.1

The Merge takes 3 datasets, one with nothing in it and various M-aware levels, everything merges as expected.

[image: Model]

This would indicate the source of the problem lies elsewhere. Modelbuilder often seems to hang on to old environment settings and in a few cases rebuilding a model from scratch seems to fix things.  I would try a new model with just a couple of outputs, one you know is creating an empty dataset and feed them into the merge tool. For me everything merged empty or not, M-aware or not....

Comment: You are right! I tried the same thing and it works! It seems like my problem is in the part where I convert my line feature class to polygon feature class. I will try to build it up again and see what will happen.

Answer (score -1):

Use Data Exists...Look at the following link!!
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/examples-of-using-logical-tools-in-modelbuilder.htm#GUID-C0E9F998-C1DE-4D52-9FCE-13543FBC0FCB

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it's an ArcGIS Pro tool, and I only have ArcGIS Desktop. Now I am aware of the _Exists_ arcpy function, but then my problem remains the same, since the _Merge_ tool takes multiple inputs.

Comment: workaround in the modelbuilder count the feature.and if count is greater than 0 then move ahead count with if then else logic..

Comment: it is there in arcmap